multiple VPN connections from the same device
I have set a VPN server (ubuntu) with a docker from the kyle/manna project. I want to establish two different VPN tunnels (VPN tunnel 1 and VPN tunnel 2) from another device (ubuntu) which owns two wireless connection (two LTE modems). Then the device which will have the VPN client will have two different interfaces called wwan0 and wwan1. How can I establish two different VPN tunnels? How can I send traffic via one VPN tunnel or the other?
In other words, I want both tunnels to be connected to the same server via different interfaces at the same time. The reason is that each tunnel will send the traffic through different cellular networks. It could happen that pne cellular network does not work at a moment and the other one does. Then the traffic could be sent via the one working


You have two interfaces, wwan0 and wwan1, and you want traffic from each to route through its respective VPN tunnel (tun0 and tun1). You need to set up routing rules to ensure that traffic from wwan0 goes through tun0, and traffic from wwan1 goes through tun1.
Add default routes in separate routing tables for each VPN tunnel:
sudo ip route add default dev tun0 table vpn_table_wwan0
sudo ip route add default dev tun1 table vpn_table_wwan1

Set up rules so that traffic originating from each interface uses the correct routing table:
sudo ip rule add from [IP_OF_WWAN0] table vpn_table_wwan0
sudo ip rule add from [IP_OF_WWAN1] table vpn_table_wwan1

Check that the rules are correctly applied:
ip rule show

You should see:
from [IP_OF_WWAN0] table vpn_table_wwan0
from [IP_OF_WWAN1] table vpn_table_wwan1

Check that the default routes in the routing tables are set correctly:
ip route show table vpn_table_wwan0
ip route show table vpn_table_wwan1

You should see default routes directing traffic through tun0 or tun1:
default via [IP_OF_TUN0] dev tun0
default via [IP_OF_TUN1] dev tun1

Ensure that the routing rules and tables are correctly configured to direct traffic from wwan0 and wwan1 through their respective VPN tunnels. Use tools like tcpdump, ping, and traceroute to confirm that traffic is routed correctly and troubleshoot any issues that arise.
